# How can i loop on each row and apply a specific function on it using sql-server

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umgmT.png)I need to loop on each resulted row from the xml code. The applied function i want to do is taking the details in first row and search in the data base for the reference information, once it is found i need to update the row with this information and so on.

here is my code that takes some information and returns a table of rows with the numbers required to get its information from the data base:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER](@PRODUCTKEY 
VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @xml as xml,@str as varchar(100),@delimiter as varchar(10)
SET @str = @PRODUCTKEY
SET @delimiter =','
SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@str,@delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)
SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)

END
```

UPDATE !!

here is the MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER function

'

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER](@PRODUCTKEY 
VARCHAR(MAX))
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @xml as xml,@str as varchar(100),@delimiter as varchar(10)
SET @str = @PRODUCTKEY
SET @delimiter =','
SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@str,@delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)
SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)





END
```

'

I need to use this function as my input parametes are " 123456,789123,4567"
so i need to take the " 123456" and apply a function on it, then the value of the function to be updated and put into the first row of the table

i need them to be listed in rows under each other not in separated tables

Comment: this is broad actually, you can do a search (Divide and conquer) like  first try on looping and then querying and updating..

Comment: What's the expected result set? A table or a xml string?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have no idea why people have upvoted this question. It is lacking the details needed to even be a complete question.

Comment: In general, in SQL, you *don't* write loops. You write queries that describe the desired result *set* and then let the optimizer work out how best to produce that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create table #ProdList (    
[ID] int identity(1,1) ,    
[ProdKey] varchar(100)    
)

--INSERT DATA INTO TEMP TABLE    
insert into #ProdList    
exec [dbo].[MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER] N'aaaa,bbbb,cccc,ddddd,eeeee'

declare @CurCount int , @MaxCount int    
select @CurCount = 1 ,@MaxCount = MAX(ID)  from #ProdList

while @CurCount <=@MaxCount    
begin    
   -- YOU CAN REPLCASE THIS CODE WITH YOUR TABLE ADN LOGIC    
   SELECT * FROM #ProdList WHERE ID = @CurCount

   SET @CurCount = @CurCount+1    
end
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explain that it is not a complete solution and what the OP needs to do.

Comment: Thanks For the solution. Although i get the result as 2 tables, the first is the number and the second is the information; i needed to update the same row with the executed information

Comment: Could you please add some more information about your source and destination table  and where\how are you going to call [dbo].[MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER] .  As per my understanding you will pass "," separated string to SP and get a list of product. after that you will search these product into some table and trying to do some update. Could you please provide some more detail?

Comment: i added the function RAHUL RICHHARIYA as you asked and i hope you got my point